# How to prevent Beamer from automatic frame break unless \framebreak explicitly

Tags: beamer

It is well known that Beamer splits one frame into multiple frames automatically if we add a frame option `allowframebreaks`. Also we can explicitly specify where to break by `\framebreak` command.

However, I would like to prevent Beamer from **automatically** breaking frames.
I want to allow Beamer to break frames only if I specify to do so, and prohibit it to do so by Beamer.

Is is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Beamer does not allow frame breaks.

Hence, you do not need to do anything to prevent frames from being broken automatically. It will not happen unless you explicitly make it happen.

Beamer considers frame breaks to be Evil; automatic frame breaks doubly so. Hence, it shuns them utterly unless you forcefully insist otherwise.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the OP wants to be able to use `\framebreak` to manually specify breaks _without_ allowing automatic breaking. With "stock" `beamer`, `\framebreak` only has an effect if `allowframebreaks` is set.

Comment: I mean, in that case, why not just break the frame into 2 frames?

Comment: I don't know, I can't speak for the OP.

Comment: I'm the OP. Yes, @PaulGessler pointed out correctly. The reason why I need this is as follows. As you know Beamer tries to put the contents fitting in one page by adjusting (narrowing) line gaps unless `allowfreambreak` option is enabled. But if `allowfreambreak` enabled, Beamer does not even try to do this and just break frames. For example, 
[Frame 1]
content 1
content 2
content 3
`\framebreak`
[Frame 2]
content 4
content 5
content 6
content 7.
 
Then, the contents 4,5,6,7 can be put in the 2nd frame if the line gap is adjusted. But Beamer puts content 7 into the third frame.

Comment: @Pengin Have you read why this is evil? That is, in the manual?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I know. But Indeed, it is convenient.

Comment: @cfr For instance, I am making two versions of the same presentation. In the handout mode, I'll expand a slide into several slides containing information that will have been present orally by the time students have access to the material. I could certainly make several frames, but it would be much more convenient (and the code will be cleaner) if I could just add more items to a single frame and break at points where it makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you just use `article` for the handout, in that case? That's what I do when I want extra material in the handout.